# Compartir contenido de <div> en Facebook

Tags: php, html5, facebook

Quisiera compartir el contenido de un `div` en Facebook, el `div` se encuentra dentro de un ciclo `for` de PHP, por lo tanto varia información es cargada en una tabla. Lo que quisiera saber es cómo compartir el contenido de cada uno de los `div` que se generan.

Con el plugin de Facebook me comparte una imagen aleatoria, con una descripción aleatoria y el titulo de mi pagina.

Este es el código que me gustaría compartir. Que sería `row->imagen`, `row->descripcion` y `row->titulo`.

¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo puede hacerse?

```
<td id="compartir"><div class="row-same-height row-full-height">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-height col-full-height border-right">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="col-md-5 blog-post-img">

        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <?php if($row->imagen == ""){?>
        <center><img src="class/imagen.png" style="max-height:500px;" alt=""></center>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <center><img src="class/<?php print($row->imagen);?>"  style="max-height:400px;" alt=""></center>    
        <?php } ?>
        <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

        <div class="col-md-7 panel-body">
          <h4 id="hola"><?php print($row->titulo);?></h4> 
          <small style="font-size:20px;">Costo: $<?php print($row->costo);?><br><a href="#"><?php print($row->categoria);?></a></small>
          <p><?php print($row->descripcion);?></p><br>

          <!-- Boton de Compartir -->
          <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://pagina.com/asdf/asdfasdf.php" data-layout="button_count"></div>
          <br><br><br><br><br> 

        </div><!--/.panel-body--> 
      </div><!--/.panel-->
    </div><!--/.col-->

</td>
```

Comment: Creo que esto puede ayudarte: [http://marcodetrabajo.com/configura-web-imagen-compartir-facebook/](http://marcodetrabajo.com/configura-web-imagen-compartir-facebook/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aquí dejo un par de opciones de cómo podría hacerse, aunque debe haber algunas más.

**Opción 1: Usando la API del feed**

Puedes usar la [API de Facebook para compartir en el feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5). De este modo podrías crear un enlace propio como éste:

> Nota: todo debería estar seguido y sin saltos de línea o fallará. Lo pongo así para que se vean mejor cada uno de los campos.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=TU_APP_ID
  &amp;display=popup
  &amp;name=Titulo%20del%20post
  &amp;caption=Un%20texto%20de%20ejemplo 
  &amp;link=https%3A%2F%2Fmi.pagina.com%2F
  &amp;redirect_uri=https://mi.pagina.com/enlace/a/redirigir
  &amp;picture=https://mi.pagina.com/enlace/a/imagen
```

y abrirlo en una ventana/pop-up para que los usuarios compartan.

Los campos que te interesan para tu caso en particular son:

- `name`: el nombre del enlace que se comparte (su valor sería `row->titulo`)
- `caption`: la descripción del enlace que se comparte (su valor sería `row->descripcion`)
- `picture`: la imagen que quieres que acompañe al enlace (su valor sería `row->imagen`). Debe tener un ancho de al menos 200 pixels.
- `link`: El enlace que se compartirá (debería ser la URL de la página).

---

**Opción 2: Usando iframes**

He visto este método en Internet, aunque no sé si es muy recomendado. La idea es usar `iframe`s, poner el botón de compartir en la página que se carga y dejar que Facebook tome la información directamente de la metadata de la página del `iframe` (metadata que se generará de manera dinámica dependiendo de los valores que se le pasen en el `src`).

Así tendrías una nueva página que por ejemplo tomaría como parámetros el nombre, la descripción y la url de la imagen, y usaría esos valores en los campos de metadata que lee Facebook:

- `og:title`: el título que quieres que se lea.
- `og:image`: la imagen.
- `og:url`: el enlace a compartir.
- `og:description`: la descripción que acompañará al enlace.

Por ejemplo el código de la metadata:

```
<meta property="og:type"   content="website" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="http://mi.pagina.com" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Titulo de la pagina" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://mi.pagina.com/link/a/imagen.jpg" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias probare las opciones y ojala funcione!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro Montoro, tuve dificultades pero con la opcion 1 me va de maravilla. Gracias :)

Comment: @AgustinAcosta, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para puntuar a Alvaro y cerrar esta pregunta.