# ¿Cómo hago para que mi juego pode compartir la puntuación de mi juego en facebook?

Tags: unity

¿De que manera puedo hacer que mi juego tenga una opción para compartir la puntuación máxima en facebook? con unity o unreal engine 4

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quizá esto te sea útil https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4135/169744

Comment: Tengo que hacer un videojuego (Runner) cuando el jugador pierde se muestra la puntuación que teiene hasta ese momento. Necesico saber como hacer para compartir esa puntuación en facebook desde el videojuego.

Comment: Exactamente esto necesito hacer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn2AMrAVBP0
pero este no funciona